# Understanding NetLogo syntax

Tags: netlogo

How should I understand the syntax of a line of code like this:

```
crt 50 [set breed ifelse-value (who mod 2 = 1) [mice] [frogs]]
```

It creates 50 turtles and set half of them to be mice and the other half to be frogs. My question is about the two reporter blocks in the `ifelse-value` statement. What does it mean that `[mice]` returns the `mice` breed.

1. How should I understand the identifier `mice`? The NetLogo manual says that NetLogo doesn't support Lisp-like symbols. But this seems to be something like that.
2. Does a code block that is expected to be a reporter and that contains an expression that can be evaluated return (report) the value of that expression?

Answer (score 3):

> How should I understand the identifier `mice`?

It's a reporter. It returns an agentset.

The NetLogo compiler turns the `mice` identifier into a parametrized call to the internal [`_breed()`](https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/blob/hexy/netlogo-gui/src/main/prim/_breed.scala) reporter. Other "breed" primitives (e.g., [`<breeds>-at`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#turtles-at)) [work the same way](https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/blob/hexy/netlogo-gui/src/main/prim/_breedat.scala).

> Does a code block that is expected to be a reporter and that contains an expression that can be evaluated return (report) the value of that expression?

Yes.

Comment: Turning `mice` into `_breed()` seems so ad hoc. I'm teaching NetLogo this semester, and am finding it difficult to lay out how the language works as a language without including quite a few ad hoc rules. For example, if instead of `[mice]` I had written `[report mice]`, that would be an error. It would be an error even if the returned valued were simply a number. But `report` is required in a `to-report` procedure. Yet the code blocks are both reporters.

Comment: @RussAbbott I don't understand the logic of what you're asking about `report`. Your question about `report` seems like something separate from your question about what `mice` is. Maybe open a new question to ask about `report`...?

Comment: @RussAbbott I would not tell your students anything about "`mice` turning to `_breed()`". That's internal, implementation-level stuff. `mice` is a reporter that takes no inputs and returns an agentset. That's all there is to it.

Comment: It makes sense to say that `mice` is a reporter that returns the agentset of mice. That's fine. What I found troubling was using that agentset as a value in the `set breed` statement in the original question. Saying `ask turtle x [set breed mice]` then means to set turtle 0's breed variable to an agentset. That seems like a strange way to think about it. I just tried `ask [breed] of turtle 1 [ set color green ]`. It works, but it looks very strange. I would think the value of the `breed` variable should be the name of a breed, not the agentset of a breed.

Comment: @RussAbbott Having the `breed` turtle variable hold a string instead of an agentset is certainly an imaginable alternative design. We made this decision circa 2002, so my memories of the design discussions on this are now dim. I suppose we thought `set breed mice` was cleaner than `set breed "mice"`. (Perhaps there was more to it than that.)